# Value Bindings in SML?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, ml

Could someone please help. I don't get the sequence of evaluation here and how we got values of "ans". e.g. in the first example there's no value of y and I'm not sure whether this returns a pair or calls x ! (fn y => y x). It would be very helpful if you can Trace each expression.

```
val x = 1
val f = (fn y => y x)
val x = 7
val g = (fn y => x - y)
val ans = f g

val ans = 6 : int

=====================================
fun f p =
let
val x = 3
val y = 4
val (z,w) = p
in
(z (w y)) + x
end
val x = 1
val y = 2
val ans = f((fn z => x + z), (fn x => x + x + 0))

val ans = 12 : int
```

Comment: Did you ask the same question twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things which help make problems like this much clearer
when trying understand an alien function [Lexical scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scoping) works.

1. add in types to the parameters and return values without modifying the program, the compiler will tell you if you get it wrong...
2. replace anonymous functions with named ones.
3. rename variable bindings that have the same names but refer to different lexical scope.
4. remove variable bindings that only get used once.

binding a value to a name does not actually perform any computation,
so is merely for the benefit of the reader, if it is not doing that job
it merely serves to obfuscate, then by all means remove it.

```
fun f (y1 : int -> 'a) = y1 1 : 'a;
fun g (y2 : int) = 7 - y2 : int;
val ans : int = f g;
```

so g is given as a parameter to f, f calls g giving it the parameter x having the value 1 making y2 = 1, which g subtracts 7 - 1 returning 6.
the return value of g is an int, thus f's 'a type when g is applied to it is an int.

for the 2nd one clean it up a bit, I pulled the anonymous fn's out into their own and named values and call f (foo, bar) to make it more readable...

```
fun f p =
 let val x = 3
     val y = 4
     val (z, w) = p
  in (z (w y)) + x end
fun foo z = z + 1;
fun bar x = x * 2;
val ans = f(foo, bar);
```

Finally, we can get rid of the let values which are only used once
and replace the (z,w) = p with just (z, w) as a parameter to the function which should be much easier to follow

```
fun f (z, w) = (z (w 4)) + 3
fun foo z = z + 1;
fun bar x = x * 2;
val ans = f(foo, bar);
val ans = ((4 * 2) + 1) + 3
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks so much :)